# Automatic Image Download From Google Lens

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-image-search, imagedownload

I need images similar to my own pictures. So I'm trying to download auto images from google lens results.[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt6Gay8nuy0)    [example link](https://lens.google.com/search?p=AfVzNa-NxKuOD0cYUqBZqf90ZSaJt0q-h_jW2mxa6gvY-3r6Ax81v3ic9gBt2jAq1l2X66V3WeDz7MkRrYk6jCCB2IMG1g7pEDiv8EvevXunIj-27T4rWMExTTPHKPBTc15XqODtv_mV7-Y9K_TsTjYIZ8y7jJiAzoAVTvoa3PQPHh-1-z6k5bCjfXohdRpEUKhgdpmIXbQkEtUQNIkOBRuv-3qm_aCRmU5oxU9w2Svl4IfukM-kZY3on-33kXJHAsHgSryQdp_ABhGRFcc_EQXHwv0RrSkzULj87Yg1eGKGaKgSRbnmoHrz1arC3qXWDMePUeRn0uK3r4ZuVFvHJixE-HHgwwDnJe8BOYgPXe87XZI5aOKIn-Ng0P8uXzDrJrp9NEStO4tmjZ31iRwAV6DnKvwWGVj_-FXqebmuQVEd5Q%3D%3D&ep=gsbubb&hl=en-TR&re=df#lns=W251bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsIkVrY0tKRGczWWpVMFptVmpMVFJoTkRrdE5HRXdPUzFoTXpJNExXRTJZV1ZsWm1RNE5URXdPQklmUVhoNGRqQkRWRFYwV1VGVldVTjFORzVoV2swMk1sY3lPV05pVTFsNFp3PT0iLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLDEsbnVsbCxbbnVsbCxudWxsLFs3NjkyLDE2MDMzLDQ0Mzk0LDg1MjMxXSxudWxsLDVdLG51bGxd)
The images in the google images section were downloaded but I could not download the images in the google lens. I would love any help. Which  parts of the code should I change ?

```
   import bs4
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# creating a directory to save images
folder_name = 'images/soup'
if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
    os.makedirs(folder_name)


def download_image(url, folder_name, num):
    # write image to file
    reponse = requests.get(url)
    if reponse.status_code == 200:
        with open(os.path.join(folder_name, str(num) + ".jpg"), 'wb') as file:
            file.write(reponse.content)


from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
chromePath='C:/Users/A/Downloads/chromedriver_win322/chromedriver.exe'
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)

# s = Service('C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/chromedriver_win322/chromedriver.exe')
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

search_URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=sulu+k%C3%B6fte&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiNiqr85YD9AhXcwwIHHT59D74Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=sulu+k&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgAMggIABCABBCxAzIICAAQgAQQsQMyBQgAEIAEMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoECAAQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BwgAELEDEEM6BQgAELEDUI8IWL4bYL8kaAFwAHgAgAG_AYgBpAiSAQMwLjiYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=FeXgY82rG9yHi-gPvvq98As&bih=722&biw=1519&hl=tr"
driver.get(search_URL)

# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]
# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[50]
# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[25]
# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[75]
# //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[350]


a = input("Waiting...")

# Scrolling all the way up
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
page_html = driver.page_source
pageSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
containers = pageSoup.findAll('div', {'class': "isv-r PNCib MSM1fd BUooTd"})
print(len(containers))
len_containers = len(containers)

for i in range(1, len_containers + 1):
    if i % 25 == 0:
        continue

    xPath = """//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[%s]""" % (i)

    previewImageXPath = """//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[%s]/a[1]/div[1]/img""" % (i)
    previewImageElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(previewImageXPath)
    previewImageURL = previewImageElement.get_attribute("src")
    # print("preview URL", previewImageURL)

    # print(xPath)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath).click()
    # time.sleep(3)

    # //*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[16]/a[1]/div[1]/img

    # input('waawgawg another wait')

    # page = driver.page_source
    # soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    # ImgTags = soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'n3VNCb', 'jsname': 'HiaYvf', 'data-noaft': '1'})
    # print("number of the ROI tags", len(ImgTags))
    # link = ImgTags[1].get('src')
    # #print(len(ImgTags))
    # #print(link)
    #
    # n=0
    # for tag in ImgTags:
    #     print(n, tag)
    #     n+=1
    # print(len(ImgTags))

    # /html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img

    # It's all about the wait
    timeStarted = time.time()
    while True:
        # driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search']").click()

        #imageElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div['
        # imageElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        #     """//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img""")
    #    imageElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a/img')
        imageElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            """//*[@id="Sva75c"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/img""")         #  titles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="srp-river-results"]//img[@class="s-item__image-img"]')

        # titles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//img[@class="s-item__image-img"]')
        imageURL = imageElement.get_attribute('src')

        if imageURL != previewImageURL:
            # print("actual URL", imageURL)
            break

        else:
            # making a timeout if the full res image can't be loaded
            currentTime = time.time()

            if currentTime - timeStarted > 10:
                print("Timeout! Will download a lower resolution image and move onto the next one")
                break

    # Downloading image
    try:
        download_image(imageURL, folder_name, i)
        print("Downloaded element %s out of %s total. URL: %s" % (i, len_containers + 1, imageURL))
    except:
        print("Couldn't download an image %s, continuing downloading the next one" % (i))
```

Comment: Seems like your provided url only points to a index of an previously uploaded image. (allready expired btw). It would make sense, to include uploading a image?

Comment: Hello, @kaliiiiiiiii I updated code and google lens link.  I download from google images.  But I can't auto download from google lens. I couldn't find the way :)